# confused about this argv use

Tags: c++, argv

```
int
main(int argc,char **argv){

for (argc--, argv++; argc > 0; argc -= argCount, argv += argCount) {
      argCount = 1;
      switch (argv[0][1]) {
      case 'q':
        testnum = atoi(argv[1]);
        argCount++;
        break;
      default:
        testnum = 1;
        break;
      }
    }
//...............
```

my question is what does the argv[0][1] mean and the condition in for() confused me i mean `for (argc--, argv++; argc > 0; argc -= argCount, argv += argCount)`

//thanks guys....**argv[0][1] should be argv[0][1],thats my mistake not the code writers.

Comment: Looks like an abuse of 'for' keyword

Comment: thats the kind of code that really lacks some comments.

Comment: The `switch` line is invalid, `argc[0][1]` is a char, not a pointer, you can't deref it once (let alone twice). Also argCount isn't defined. Please post the real code.

Comment: `**argv[0][1]` doesn't make sense. `argv[0][1]` already yields a `char`, which you can't just dereference. This code shouldn't compile. I assume the real code is just `argv[0][1]`, and then it just tests the second character of the current argument string.

Comment: argCount defination i forgot to put it on ...sorry

Comment: It's also undefined behavior if you invoke it "`prog -q`".  It's a good example of how not to write code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv[0]` represents the name of the program as it was invoked on the command line. If you typed `./myprogram --help`, then `argv[0]` would be "./myprogram".

`argv[0][1]` will be the second character of that string, '/' in the example above.

---

Let’s see that `for (argc--, argv++; argc > 0; argc -= argCount, argv += argCount)`:

It initializes the loop by doing `argc--` then `argv++` (`argv` now points to the second user parameter string) and argc declares an argument less.

The loop is for all arguments `argc>0`, and at every iteration, the number of treated arguments `argCount` is taken off the number of all arguments `argc`. That makes sense.

However `switch (**argv[0][1])` doesn’t make any sense, `argv[0][1]` is a `char`, as seen before, not a pointer, so it cannot be dereferenced.

Answer (score 2):

That code doesn't look correct. `**argv[0][1]` tries to dereference a `char`.

`argv[0][1]` would make sense, and means "take the second `char` of the first `char*` in `argv`." IMHO, the code is trying to detect a `-q` command-line flag (and subsequently setting `testnum` to the `int` version of the next argument, blindly assuming it is present), but it's skipping checking for the `-`, and blindly assuming it's there, and no other arguments would ever have `q` as  a second character.

This code needs to be refactored. Here's one way:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int testnum = 1;
    for (int argi = 1; argi < argc; ++argi) {
        if(argv[argi][0] == '-') {
            switch (argv[argi][1]) {
            case 'q':
                if(argi + 1 == argc || argv[argi + 1][0] == '-') {
                    /* Handle missing argument error. */
                    return 1;
                }
                testnum = atoi(argv[++argi]);
                break;
            default:
               /* Handle unrecognized flag error. */
               return 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /* Handle non-flag parameter. */
        }

    /* Continue with program. */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Definitly looks like somebody was trying to be "clever". Also, the code doesn't skip every other argument when a `-q` was found, it just skips the argument directly after that one. `argCount` is reset to `1` inside the loop body.

Comment: @Xeo: I agree with the `clever`, notably the fact that `quorum` or (`-quorum` in Mike's version) is handled as if it were `q` (resp. `-q`) bothers me to no end. At the very least a check that what comes after the `q` is the null character should be done (if one wishes to keep the switch structure).

Comment: @Matthieu: Actually, I did it that way so it could be extended later to handle multiple flags (e.g. `-qavv` would be an alternative to `-q -a -v -v`) by putting a loop around the `switch`. Alternatively, one could declare that the parameter could come immediately after the letter, i.e. `-qfoo` does the same thing as `-q foo`.

Comment: @Xeo: No, I'm pretty sure he does *not* mean a whitespace character. All the parameters in `argv` are null-terminated strings, and it's the shell's job to split up parameters, not the program's. `foo -q bar bob` sets `argc` to `4` and `argv` to `{ "foo", "-q", "bar", "bob"}`. If you want a space in there, you'll need to quote it in the shell, e.g. `foo -q' bar'` gives you `int argc = 2; char* argv[] = {"foo", "-q bar"};`.

Comment: @Mike: Yeah, I kinda misunderstood. Of course it should be a null character.

Answer (score 0):

This code looks very crazy. I guess you intended to do the following:

```
int main(int argc,char **argv){
 char** p = argv + 1;  // skipping program name

 while (*p != 0) {     // over all parameters
  testnum = 1;
  if (*p[1] == 'q') {  // skipping - of "-q", not a good idea
    p ++;
    if (*p != 0) {     // may be null, read testnum from parameter,
                       // ?? no check whether this is an integer at all
       testnum = atoi(*p);
    }
  }
}
```

(not tested, may not compile nor work)